# SharpDX crash when rendering h264 video using MediaFoundation

Tags: c#, directx-11, directx-9, sharpdx

I am looping a h264 video in a SharpDX app and occasionally I am getting a crash which I am unable to find the cause.

```
SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0xC00D36BA], Module: [Unknown], ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], Message: Unknown
at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
at SharpDX.MediaFoundation.MediaFactory.GetService(ComObject unkObjectRef, Guid guidService, Guid riid, IntPtr& vObjectOut)
```

it is called in this function:

```
    public static Surface GetSurfaceFromMediaBuffer(MediaBuffer videoBuffer)
    {
        IntPtr surfacePtr;

        MediaFactory.GetService(videoBuffer, mMrBufferService, typeof (Surface).GUID, out surfacePtr);

        return new Surface(surfacePtr);
    }
```

is there something related to Surface or MediaBuffer which needs Disposing?

this is on win7, 32bit.

Comment: could you check your buffersize?

Comment: what buffersize exactly do you mean?

Comment: how are you passing videoBuffer in your code? is it in some loop?

Comment: Try to turn on the native debugging to get more information. Instructions can be found [here](http://sharpdx.com/forum/4-general/1774-how-to-debug-a-sharpdxexception) and [here](http://sharpdx.org/forum/5-api-usage/26-general-recommandations-for-debugging).

Comment: afaik, the DeviceCreationFlags.Debug is requiring the DirectX SDK to be installed. however on the machine where this is happening only the DirectX runtime is installed and i have no option to install the SDK. :(

Comment: Without proper debugging it will be difficult to find the real issue. As a guess - check the resource usage (RAM/VRAM) and make sure that you are disposing correctly all used resources (specially those created in the render loop).

Comment: ok, eventually i did manage to install the DX SDK and the Windows SDK. however it is still crashing upon startup. i posted this in another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810462/launching-sharpdx-directx-app-with-devicecreationflags-debug