# Launching SharpDX/DirectX app with DeviceCreationFlags.Debug

Tags: c#, directx-11, directx-9, sharpdx

I am trying to launch my directX/SharpDX app with `DeviceCreationFlags.Debug` but i am getting the following crash upon startup:

```
SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0x80004005], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_FAIL/Unspecified error], Message: Unspecified error

at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateDevice(Adapter adapter, DriverType driverType, DeviceCreationFlags flags, FeatureLevel[] featureLevels)
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device..ctor(Adapter adapter, DeviceCreationFlags flags, FeatureLevel[] featureLevels)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.GraphicsDevice..ctor(GraphicsAdapter adapter, DeviceCreationFlags flags, FeatureLevel[] featureLevels)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GamePlatform.CreateDevice(GraphicsDeviceInformation deviceInformation)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice(GraphicsDeviceInformation newInfo)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GraphicsDeviceManager.ChangeOrCreateDevice(Boolean forceCreate)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GraphicsDeviceManager.SharpDX.Toolkit.IGraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice()
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.InitializeBeforeRun()
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GameWindowDesktop.Run()
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GamePlatform.Run(GameContext gameContext)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.Run(GameContext gameContext)
at wrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This is on Win7 32bit and i do have the June2010 DirextX SDK and Runtime installed as well as the Windows SDK for Windows 7.

btw, this question originated from this one: [SharpDX crash when rendering h264 video using MediaFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809281/sharpdx-crash-when-rendering-h264-video-using-mediafoundation)

Comment: From your question, I assume it works without the debug flag?

Comment: yes it runs without debug flag.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN (page on D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_FLAG):

**D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG**

Creates a device that supports the debug layer.

To use this flag, you must have D3D11*SDKLayers.dll installed; otherwise, device creation fails. To get D3D11_1SDKLayers.dll, install the SDK for Windows 8.

These files are not part of the June2010 SDK. You have to find them somewhere else (i.e. in the Windows 8 SDK, as suggested).

Comment: actually i am running this in win7 and i do have the SDK for Windows 7 installed. anyways i will check if this specific dll is present.

Comment: you are right, this DLL seems to be missing. where can i get it if not the Windows SDK?

Comment: It says to install the SDK for Windows **8**. Don't know whether there's another way of getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to installing the SDK is installing Visual Studio 2012 or newer. Its installation will install these debug libraries.
Similar problem was mentioned here: [link](http://sharpdx.org/forum/5-api-usage/3333-d3d11-initialization-problem#3702) => explanation 3