# SharpDX Device-Debug. crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, sharpdx

I'm trying to use the sharpDX debug function but as soon as I run my application with the "DeviceCreationFlags.Debug" Visual Studio crashes and I get this:
[image]

If I change the Flags to None everything works fine. any Idea? It says "The application tried to call a SDK function that isn't existing or not available

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810462/launching-sharpdx-directx-app-with-devicecreationflags-debug) about the same issue - in few words, to be able to use Debug flag you need to have installed DirectX Debug layer - which comes with Win SDK for Win8/8.1 environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you guys will get this same error, just download the windows 8.1 SDK it will fix this issue